# React Redux is creating unnecessary indexes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to get data from my server and format that data into an indexed array and storing that in my store. The problem is when I try to manually define the indexes Redux automatically nulls any indexes that were undefined. Because I have one index with a very large number Redux indexes many unnecessary items and crashes.

Image of the bug:

[image]

Image of my code:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `langStrings[i].LayoutTypeId` is an huge number and if you do `filteredLangStrings[langStrings[i].LayoutTypeId] = []` javascript creates an array of length `langStrings[i].LayoutTypeId` with all the elements set to `null`.

To avoid this, you should change your `filteredLangStrings` shape in this way:

```
let filteredLangStringsIndex = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < langStrings.length; i++) {
  if(langStrings[i].LanguageId === langId) {
     let index = langStrings[i].LayoutTypeId;
     
     if (langStrings[i].Msg !== "") {
        filteredLangStrings[filteredLangStringsIndex] = {};
        filteredLangStrings[filteredLangStringsIndex].index = index;
        filteredLangStrings[filteredLangStringsIndex].Msg = langStrings[i].Msg;      ​
       ​ filteredLangStringsIndex ++;
    ​}
 ​ }
}
```

This creates something like:

```
filteredLangStringsIndex = {"0": {index: 89746, Msg: "message"}, 
                            "1": {index: 54543, Msg: "another message"}, ...}
```

In this way you have a smaller `filteredLangStringsIndex` by keeping `index` and `Msg` informations.

Comment: This helped a lot, thanks.

Comment: @JalenMuller happy to ear that. Have a nice coding =)